# How is this Huffman tree converted into electric voltages?

Tags: compression

This is the Huffman tree for word "stackexchange":

[image]

How is this Huffman tree converted into electric voltages?

Comment: not at all. It's a data structure. an analogous question would be: "Here's a CAD drawing of the Burj Khalifa, how is a CAD drawing converted into electric voltages".

Comment: If it's a **binary** tree, then every 1 is converted to a 5V, and every 0 is converted to a 0V. Or you may be using 3.3V instead of 5V.